# How to say "succession of actions" (linguistics) in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

How to say "succession of actions" (linguistics) in Japanese?

The context here is linguistics, as for instance, "The conjunct "and" is used to express a succession of actions".

I found that 'succession' is said 連続 and I bet it is the correct word for this expression.
But I can't find the correct word for 'action' here. From different searches on Google, I found some instances of "作用の連続" or "アクションの連続", but I don't know, it seems it is not so common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the technical term, but just as a Japanese phrase, the most likely is 連続した動作. 動作の連続 may work as well. The difference between the two is the emphasis is on *action* in the former, *succession* in the latter.

Comment: Just after publishing my question, I found the word 行動 used in a linguistic context. Would 行動の連続 be ok?

Comment: @starckman Yes, the same applies to 連続した行動/行動の連続. (To me, however, these sound less idiomatic than 連続した動作/動作の連続.)

Comment: What is the difference between 行動 and 動作 then?

Comment: @starckman 行動/動作 is like *action/movement*. 行動 feels like including the will of the acter. When it is about objective description, 動作 sounds better to me.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As a linguistic term, we say **継起【けいき】** (literally: "successive occurrence").

For example, from a random [English learning website](https://englischool.com/participial-construction/):

> 2-1. 継起「～して」
>
> Taking a key out f my bag, I opened the box. 私はかばんから鍵を取り出して、その箱を開けた。

Comment: Thank you very much. In which case must I use 継起 and in which case 動作の連続?

Comment: @starckman I never heard of 動作の連続 in grammatical discussion. It'd be closer to saying "an action after another" in English.